# How should I use Write-Host so that pipeline and parameter input behave the same way?

Tags: powershell, foreach, pipeline

I have a PowerShell script that takes pipeline input, processes each item, and then calls `Write-Host` on each one.

When I call the script using parameter input, my `foreach` loop writes out a single header row, and then the data below it. When called via the pipeline, I get one header row and one data row for each row of input. I guess PowerShell has some code that figures out when you're doing a `Write-Host` in a `foreach` loop and only writes the header once in that case.

So my question is, how should I be going about this so that the behavior is consistent between both forms of input? I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, but I don't know what the right way is.

Here's my script.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [PSObject[]] $InputObject
)

process {
    $lines = ($InputObject | Out-String) -replace "`r", "" -split "`n"

    foreach ($line in $lines) {
        #Process $line here

        Write-Host $line
    }
}
```

And here are two sample outputs

[`MyScript.ps1 $(ps | Select-Object -First 10)`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yneFXPXS)

[`$(ps | Select-Object -First 10) | MyScript.ps1`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XU22um9k)

Comment: I've wrestled with this myself and have not found an answer. It seems that when you pipe things into the function it processes the entire function once per item in an array, but if you call it with arguments it will perform the Begin section once, then the Process against each item, then the End section once. I know that doesn't solve the problem, but hopefully it gives more insight into what's happening.

Comment: A complicated answer involves Trace-Command which would break down in great detail what happens between the two occurances. `Trace-Command -name ParameterBinding -Option All -Expression { $(ps | Select-Object -First 1) | .\pipeTest.ps1} -FilePath c:\temp\tracePipe.txt`. The output is too verbose for me. Maybe someone with more experience can chime in.

Comment: One difference i see is that where the pipe is used for the input object the bind shows as `BIND arg [] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL` where the paramenter is passed in example `MyScript.ps1 $(ps | Select-Object -First 10)` the the bind shows as `BIND arg [System.Object[]] to param [InputObject]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the as designed behavior for cmdlets that take pipeline input. When input is pipelined, each object is treated individually, but if you pass the collection as the InputObject the collection is treated as a single object.

You can try it with `Select-Object`. There is a distinct difference between

```
ps | Select -First 1
```

and

```
Select -First 1 -InputObject (ps)
```

In your case, pipelining causes each object to run through the out-string processing step which prints a header for it. However, when you use the InputObject parameter the collection is sent to Out-String resulting in a single header.

To make your function consistent with other cmdlets and functions you should design your process step to handle a single item from the pipelined input. Otherwise, be prepared to handle the case where you get a collection as single object.

There is an open [connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/716546/where-object-select-object-inputobject-parameter-does-not-work-as-expected) on this, but I doubt it will get fixed as it is the as designed behavior, I believe. It looks like in newer versions of PowerShell they are just clarifying the actual behavior in the help. From the help for `Select-Object` in PowerShell 4:

> When you use the InputObject parameter with Select-Object, instead of piping command results to Select-Object, the InputObject value-even if the value is a collection that is the result of a command, such as -InputObject (Get-Process)-is treated as a single object.

Also, typically when you have InputObject, its type is just `PSObject`, not an array.

Comment: Okay cool. I was aware of what was going on, but I didn't realize that all the other scripts did it that way. I'll just go on the assumption that pipelining in is the way to go.